# jni memory leak in java threads on ubuntu

Tags: java, memory, java-native-interface

we call a jni method in a java thread pool. the jni method loads a so library, in which it requests memory dynamically (new and then delete). found that the number of memory leaks is actually associated with the number of threads created. memory leaks every time, no matter wheather we shut down the thread pool. it seams that native memory will not be released at all. is there anything wrong we have done? hope to get your help.

**this is java code:**

```
// create a thread pool
ExecutorService getExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

// do jobs in threads
for (int i = 0 ; i < jobCount ; i++ ) {
    // do job through threadpool
    // create a TaskWithResult object, in which jni method Generate(...) is called
    TaskWithResult execute = new TaskWithResult(inputDir, outputDir, jsonFilePath);
    // summit
    Future<String> future = getExecutorService.submit((execute));
} 

// shut down threadpool
try {
    getExecutorService.shutdown(); 

    if(!getExecutorService.awaitTermination(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
       getExecutorService.shutdownNow();  
    }
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    getExecutorService.shutdownNow();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**this is jni code:**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_jniso_CppSvr_Generate
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring inputDir, jstring outputDir, jstring jsonFilePath)
{
    // test memory leak
    DataTest dt;
    // request a large amount of memory, for instance 20MB, in c++ method Gen()
    dt.Gen();

    return 1;
}
```

**Add c++ code here**

```
void DataTest::Gen()
{
    char *big_data = new char[1024 * 1024 * 20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 20; ++i) {
        big_data[i] = 0;
    }
    delete[] big_data;
}
```

requests 20mb memory and it seams that leads to 20mb leak in each thread.

[image: use pmap -x to watch memory. there's ten 20MB still resident in memory after the thread pool is shut down]

Comment: _"is there anything wrong we have done?"_ That's hard for us to say since you haven't really shown us any of your C++ memory management.

Comment: Note that not all memory management libraries give memory back to the OS. Some prefer to hold on to it (as unused virtual memory) for later.

Comment: @Michael, i posted c++ code.

Comment: @Botje thanks. it's all about memory management. the article helps me a lot. https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/understanding-glibc-malloc/